# How to hide multiple views at a time in effective manner in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, logic

In my current project I need to maintain multiple container controllers in a single view controller. There are four buttons on view controller. if first button is selected first container will be visible and remaining will be in hidden state. Similarly to second, third and fourth button. At any time only one will be visible to the user.  I can achieve it by showing the respective container and hiding rest by hardcoding.

```
@property UIView *view1;
@property UIView *view2;
@property UIView *view3;
@property UIView *view4;

- (iBAction *)firstButtonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
self.view1.hidden = NO;
self.view2.hidden = YES;
self.view3.hidden = YES;
self.view4.hidden = YES;
}

- (iBAction *)secondButtonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
self.view1.hidden = YES;
self.view2.hidden = NO;
self.view3.hidden = YES;
self.view4.hidden = YES;
}

- (iBAction *)thirdButtonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
self.view1.hidden = YES;
self.view2.hidden = YES;
self.view3.hidden = NO;
self.view4.hidden = YES;
}

- (iBAction *)fourthButtonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
self.view1.hidden = YES;
self.view2.hidden = YES;
self.view3.hidden = YES;
self.view4.hidden = NO;
}
```

But I am not satisfied with the approach. I tried searching answer in stack overflow but not successful. 
 Please tell me know if any body knows any effective approach to achieve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few possible solutions to this. Here's one option.

First, give each button a specific tag. Give button 1 a tag of 1. Give button 2 a tag of 2, etc.

Then use a single action for all four buttons instead of the four separate actions you have now.

Then implement the one action method like this:

```
- (IBAction *)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
    self.view1.hidden = button.tag != 1;
    self.view2.hidden = button.tag != 2;
    self.view3.hidden = button.tag != 3;
    self.view4.hidden = button.tag != 4;
}
```

If the button with a tag of 1 is tapped, then `button.tag != 1` will be false so `self.view1.hidden` will be set to `NO`. The other 3 conditions will be true so the other buttons will have `hidden` set to `YES`.

The same logic applies to the other three buttons each with their own tag values.

Answer (score 2):

Give the views tags like 201 to 204 or anything you like, set the for loop accordingly.

Point the actions of all the buttons to the below selector,

```
- (void)anyButtonClicked:(UIButton *)button 
{

    for (int iterator = 201; iterator < 204; iterator ++) 
    {
        UIView *currentView = [self.view viewWithTag:iterator];

        if (currentView.tag == button.tag) 
        {

            [currentView setHidden:NO];

        } else {

            [currentView setHidden:YES];
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this it will also consume less memory-

```
[yourview removeFromSuperview];
        yourview = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

At any time only one view is hidden. Why do you need to hide/unhide all of them? Just do the following (just after the `@property` declarations):

```
UIView *lastVisible = view1;
```

And then you can write the actions as:

```
- (IBAction *)firstButtonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
lastVisible.hidden = YES;
self.view1.hidden = NO;
lastVisible = self.view1;
}
```

and so on. This assumes that view1 is the visible view at first.